How to produce a dough in 1 day instead of 2?
We have a recipe of Whole wheat dough with the following ingredients:

Whole wheat
Sunflour Oil
Milk
Water
Salt

This dough we mix for 20 minutes, then let it rest refrigerated at 1'C for 12 to 18 hours. After 18 hours we put it back in the mixer, and stir it with hot water between 15 to 20 minutes. This is the only way we have achieved a great dough to insert into a intrusion machine.
If we do not do this process of 2 days, but put the dough in the intrusion machine same day, the final product will come out with a very broken finish not a compact well done finish. We have tried a lot of combinations to achieve great dough to use in the intrusion machine with no success on end product.
How can we reduce the process from 2 days to 1 day, and have a great final product result? This 2 day process is taking a toll on our machines and our time to produce.

Do you mean "extrusion?"   What type of dough?  What is it that you are making?

have you attempted to let it rest at room temperature? in bread making, this would be a "warm" ferment or "room temperature" ferment stage, which happens a lot faster and develops really nice flavor. an extrusion process implies pasta or something to me, but perhaps you can leverage the same technique and speed up your process.

I have no idea what sort of machinery you are talking about or how to make dough to suit it, but when in a hurry with bread dough, warmer is the way to get there, generally. But your dough has no yeast, so presumably it is pasta or somehting like that...

It's unclear what process or machines you're using.  However, with dough there are somethings you can try:

Autolyse dough: After your 20 minute mix, let it relax at room temperature for 20-30 minutes.  Then mix for a brief period (less than a minute).  Repeat this process 3 times.  Then place in the fridge for shorter time than 12 hrs (I'd start with 4hrs).
Use dough relaxer or conditioning enzymes.  There are chemicals you can add to the dough to make this process go faster.  An example would be dough strengtheners by novozymes or I've heard of Bromelain being used to relax dough. [I'm not a food chemist].

